# How can I open a new display when outgoing call is made in android?

Tags: android, phone-call

I am trying to open an intent when outgoing call is made. But the app crashes.
Am i missing something or this cannot be done?
Or is there a way to open a different screen  (activity/fragment) between call creation event and receiver's receiving call event ?

Comment: please post some cost with what you've tried

Answer (score 2):

From the [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html):

> **Listening for outgoing call requests**
>
> Apps that provide phone calling services (such as VOIP or number
>   management) can set up Intent filters to handle outgoing call
>   requests, such as those made from the Dialer or other installed apps.
>   This provides a seamless integration for the user, who can transition
>   directly to the calling service without having to redial or launch
>   another app.
>
> When the user initiates a call, the system notifies interested apps by
>   sending an ordered broadcast of the `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` Intent,
>   attaching the original phone number, URI, and other information as
>   extras. This gives apps such as Google Voice and others a chance to
>   modify, reroute, or cancel the call before it’s passed to the system’s
>   default phone app.
>
> If you want your phone calling app to be able to handle outgoing call
>   requests, implement a broadcast receiver that receives the
>   `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` Intent, processes the number, and initiates a call
>   as needed. Make sure to declare an intent filter for `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`
>   in the receiver, to let the system know that your app is interested in
>   the broadcast. You’ll also need to request the `PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS`
>   permission in order to receive the Intent.
>
> Note that the system broadcasts `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` only for numbers
>   that are not associated with core dialing capabilities such as
>   emergency numbers. This means that `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` can not interfere
>   with access to emergency services the way your use of `CALL_PRIVILEGED`
>   might.
>
> Here’s an example broadcast receiver declared in an app’s manifest
>   file:
>
> ```
> <manifest>
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />  
>     <application>
>         ...
>         <receiver android:name=MyOutgoingCallHandler">
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>             </intent-filter>
>         </receiver>
>         ...
>     </application>
> </manifest>
> ```
>
> The implementation of the corresponding broadcast receiver would look
>   something like this:
>
> ```
> public class MyOutgoingCallHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {
>   @Override
>   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>     // Extract phone number reformatted by previous receivers
>     String phoneNumber = getResultData();
>     if (phoneNumber == null) {
>       // No reformatted number, use the original
>       phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
>     }
>     // My app will bring up the call, so cancel the broadcast
>     setResultData(null);
>     // Start my app to bring up the call
>     ...
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Because the `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` broadcast is ordered, your app can
>   choose whether to consume the call request itself or simply process
>   the number and pass the result data on to other apps that may be
>   interested. In this example, the broadcast receiver brings up a phone
>   call on it’s own service and sets the result data to null. This
>   prevents the call request from reaching the default phone app.